# Enable Javascript in WKWebView iOS 9

Tags: ios9, wkwebview

I was successfully using a WKWebView to load a url in iOS 8 using Xcode 6.4. I've upgraded to Xcode 7 and now the my WKWebView does not have Javascript enabled any longer. How do I enable Javascript in my WebView again?

Comment: Did you also upgrade to iOS 9? The title makes it sound like ios9 is the culprit but your question seems to blame Xcode. Maybe revise your wording?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is enabled by default. There is a `javaScriptEnabled` property on `WKPreferences` that you can flip to `true` in case some code has turned it off.

Are you sure that the problem you are seeing is related to JavaScript? Do you see any errors in the console? Did you implement the error/failure delegate methods to catch problems?

My gut feeling is that you are running into something different. For example a resource not loading because of the new [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) requirements in iOS9.